# crontab reading script(s)

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the script to show both the `date` and the `netstat -a | grep`, but it's just showing one of them:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/armando.se
touch textfil1.txt
chmod 755 textfil1.txt
netstat -a | grep tcp &> date +"%Y-%m-%d" >textfil1.txt
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: i want the scirpt to read both the date and te netstat -a,cant get it work, just getting one of them

Comment: You can [edit] your post to have the question in it, and any other information someone would need to answer it.

Comment: just did, was on a hurry lol :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/armando.se
netstat -a | grep tcp > textfil1.txt
date +"%Y-%m-%d" >> textfil1.txt
chmod 755 textfil1.txt
```

where

- `>>` is append operator
- there is no need to `touch` a file before crating it

Comment: tyyyy man, it worked :DDD <333

Answer (score 0):

`grep >& date` redirects the output of `grep` into `date`'s standard input. `date` doesn't read its standard input, so that's just a black hole.

You can just run the commands in sequence instead using [grouping braces](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping):

```
{ netstat -a | grep tcp ; date +"%Y-%m-%d" } >textfile1.txt
```

You could also use [`>>` to append](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) to the file, and run both commands separately.

Comment: still just showing the tcp ports... :S

Comment: I don't think it is.